# Cannot access Online Help in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Running VS2008 Pro on Windows 7, all SP and hotfixes installed.

When I click F1 on a (valid) keyword in VS2008, I only receive the "Information Not Found" page. I know I didn't install the full msdn as I just wanted to use online help.  I can't recall if I clicked or unclicked anything during the install process (installed a couple of months ago so I don't fully remember) that related to help but I did try to pare down the install size by unclicking things I know I wouldn't ever use.

devenv.exe and dexplore.exe are both set to run as admin.  Tools-Options-Help-Online is set to use online first, then local.  All options are checked.  Equally odd, the Codezone provider download button gives me a dialog indicating it couldn't download resources.

My router is Smoothwall with the transparent proxy enabled.. meaning, I don't have to enter anything in a web browser for a proxy - I just surf.

Comment: Had the same problem, but after going to Tools > Options > Help > General and setting Show help using = Integrated help viewer it surprisingly started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Select "**Tools > Options > Help > Online**".

Additionally there are a couple of list boxes one labelled "Search these providers:" Make sure "MSDN Online" is there and checked.

If it's not there you'll need to reinstall the MSDN.

Comment: Does that mean that MSDN (installed locally) is required in order to access online help?

Comment: @John - I don't think you have to install the content locally, just the hooks. It's been a while since I installed VS2008 so I can't remember the options, but there should be an "online only" option.